# Java won't run my eclipse program after being exported

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to use eclipse to write a simple text-based game, but whenever I export it, The executable jar file pulls up an error of "could not find or load main class." I'm a bit of a noob, so if I'm doing something stupid, please don't hesitate to point it out. I've searched for hours trying to figure it out, but haven't come up with anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
package dsadsa;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class UserInput {
public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner Jameson = new Scanner(System.in); 
  double fans, sans, tans, foans, fians, sians;
  System.out.println("You are walking down a road when a mysterious character exits an alleyway and proceeds to follow you.");
  System.out.println("Do you 0:run or 1:fight ?");
  fans = Jameson.nextDouble();      
  if (fans == 0) {
      System.out.println("You break in to a run down the road, but no matter how fast you go, the man seems to keep pace with you.");
      System.out.println("Do you 0:keep running or 1:turn and ask why he is following you ?");
      sans = Jameson.nextDouble();
      if (sans == 0) {
          System.out.println("You continue to try to escape the man, but he is faster then you, he eventually catches up to you and tackles you.");
          System.out.println("Do you 0:Scream for help or 1:Fight back ?");
          tans = Jameson.nextDouble();
          if (tans == 0) {
              System.out.println("You scream for help, but there is nobody near to hear you, the man puts a bag over your head and carries you into the alley he originally came out of.");
              System.out.println("Game Over.");
          } else {
              System.out.println("You make an attempt to throw the man off you, but he is incredibly heavy. He raises a fist and puches you in the head, knocking you out. Game Over.");
          }
      } else {
          System.out.println("You turn and ask the man why he is following you, he does not respond. His hoodie is completely covering his face, so that none of his features are visible.");
          System.out.println("Do you 0:Ask him again or 1:Walk up to him and pull back his hood ?");
          tans = Jameson.nextDouble();
          if (tans == 0) {
              System.out.println("You ask the man again why he was following you, he once again says nothing. Are you deaf? You ask him.");
              System.out.println("The man proceeds to pull a shining blade from within his cloak. You did not expect this. He walks forward to you and promptly slays you.");
              System.out.println("Game Over.");
          } else {
              System.out.println("You walk forward and pull back his hood. You immediately scream in horror, his face is blank except for a slit that must be his mouth.");
              System.out.println("He has no lips and his skin is completely white. You break into a sprint, adrenaline rushing through your body. You make it home, and the creature seems to have stayed behind.");
              System.out.println("Do you 0:lock the doors or 1:grab a weapon ?");
              foans = Jameson.nextDouble();
              if (foans == 0) {
                  System.out.println("You immediately turn and lock the door, terrified by your encounter. You walk upstairs and get into your bed, you lie awake for hours before you finally drift off to sleep.");
                  System.out.println(" You awake well-rested, but you soon realise that you are no longer in your own house, but in a completely different one. You walk around the house and find nothing unusual,");
                  System.out.println(" but as you look out the door, you realise there is nothing there. You have been trapped in a simulation by an alien race. Game Over.");
              } else {
                  System.out.println("You run to your room and grab a shotgun that you keep in a gun locker under your bed. You walk to the window and see the creature slowly approaching your door.");
                  System.out.println("Do you 0:run to lock the door  or 1:shoot the creature from your room ?");
                  fians = Jameson.nextDouble();
                  if (fians == 0) {
                      System.out.println("You run to the door and bolt it shut, trapping the creature outside. After a minute, you hear the door handle shaking.");
                      System.out.println("Do you 0:shoot the creature throught the door or 1:call the police ?");
                      sians = Jameson.nextDouble();
                      if (sians == 0) {
                          System.out.println("You shoot the creature through the door, but this only aggravates it, it bashes through the door and slays you. Game Over."); 
                      } else {
                          System.out.println("You call the police, telling them that there is a man outside the door trying to get in, so that they won't think you're insane. The End.");
                          System.out.println(" They come promptly and once they realise that the creature is not really a man, they request permission from the government to shoot, permission is granted, and the creature is killed.");
                          System.out.println(" You have just stopped a large-scale alien invasion on planet earth, of which the creature was leader, the government thanks you and you are awarded $10,000.");
                          System.out.println("Congratulations! You have beaten the game! Thanks for playing!"); 
                      }
                  } else {
                      System.out.println("You shoot the creature through the window and it collapses onto the porch. Unfortunately, the glass shatters back into your face and you eventually bleed out. Game Over.");
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  } else {
      System.out.println("You turn and punch the man, but he does not seem to be effected by it, he proceeds to fight back, nailing you in the face and knocking you out clean.");
      System.out.println("You awake in a trash bin in the middle of nowhere. Game Over.");
  }
  Jameson.close();}
 }
```

Comment: Looking at the problem description, there is no issue with your code. Did your jar has MANIFEST.MF and does your MANIFEST.MF has 'main-class' defined. Look at this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

Comment: I'd strongly suggest not to depend on your IDE for build purposes. More often than not you will run into problems as soon as your code is built on a built server when you do not keep your build configuration up to date. Build your project manually at least once a day. Manually with something like Ant, Maven or Gradle, that is.

Answer (score 3):

You have coded your text-based game to run in the command line therefore you cannot package it as a `jar` because default your os will run `javaw.exe` which won't support the command line it needs to be run from `java.exe`, if you look in your project>bin there should be a file called UserInput.class you have will have to open cmd to this folder and run `java UserInput`(without the '.class' extension). If, however, you want to package it for someone a little less technical then your solution will be to make a simple GUI using Swing and a `ConsoleWindow` which I found [here](http://exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/javax.swing.text/ta_Console.html). Once you have made you can use it as follows:

```
    //This makes our console object which we can get input or write to, the class mentioned in the link must be in the same directory in Eclipse as this one
    try {
        Console console = new Console();
    }catch (IOException e) {}

    //Our input scanner we use console.piOut instead of System.in
    Scanner s = new Scanner(console.piOut);

    String sample = s.nextLine(); //Gets some input

    //Makes a printer where we can write to the console:
    PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(console.poOut);

    //Simple HelloWorld same usage as System.out.println() etc
    printer.println("Hello");

    printer.println("You said: " + sample);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, might be something silly

On eclipse there is the option to export your project to jar
1. select "Runnable JAR file", then next

On the screen "Runnable JAR File Specification"
1. On launch configuration select UserInput - 
2. Select destination file. Eg c:\game.jar
3. Library handling -> package required libraries into generated JAR
4. finish

The you run your code via command line:
java -cp game.jar dsadsa.UserInput